# swift Navigation Bar doesnt appear

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

i have a problem i never had before. Normally i'm creating a

> Navigation Controller --> BottomBarNavigationController --> Controller --> Detail Controller
>   logic. 
>   The result is that i see a navigation bar at the top. Right now its shown in the editor but not at the emulator.

[image: Here is my Storyboard:]

And here is the resutl at the emulator:
[image: Screenshot]

Here is the code i'm pushing to detail viewcontroller:

```
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showChat", sender: self)
```

Comment: can you show the code you wrote to push this controller?

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: Make sure the Segue kind is "Show" not "Present Modally". Can you check?

Comment: yep it is set to show

Comment: the screen is being presented from left to right or from the bottom?

Comment: from left to right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current View controller is showing the navigation bar but the next controller is not, then these could be the possible cases:

1. You are presenting the controller instead of pushing it to navigation stack.
2. If you are using segue, you might have selected Segue kind as "Present Modally" instead of "Show"
3. Your current view controller viewWillDisapper function says navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true which hides the navigation bar as soon as the current view disappears.
4. Your destination view controller is hiding the navigation bar somewhere in code.
5. Your CurrentViewController is not embedded in a NavigationController.

Comment: you were right, it was in view will appear method thank you